# Ubuntu doesn't detect eth0

Tags: dual-boot, ethernet

I use dual-boot Ubuntu 14.04 / Windows 8.1. I formatted Windows, but grub didn't catch Windows. So I used [`boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and it worked well except one thing...

Ubuntu doesn't detect `eth0` after I used `boot-repair`.

Windows(via dual-boot) and liveUSB (Ubuntu) detect and can use Ethernet, but Ubuntu cannot.

**Settings**

```
$ ifconfig

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:120128 (120.1 KB)  TX bytes:120128 (120.1 KB)

$ lshw -C network

  *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 0c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f6100000-f6100fff memory:ec100000-ec103fff

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

When I excute `dmesg | grep eth0`, it display no results. but `lspci | grep Ethernet` has a result as below.

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Did you recall how you fixed this?

Comment: Unfortunately, too much time has gone now, I can't remember that precisely. But I guess I reinstalled totally because I did not find out the solution. Just guess..